# What are some sources of recommendations of Mathematical books - both Recreational and Popular Mathematics as well as Technical Mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, big-list, popular-math

I'm a lover of books about Mathematics. However, I have noticed it's quite hard to stay in touch with new releases or book reviews in the world of Mathematics. I use GoodReads for recommendations in most genres of Fiction and it does a good job, but it very rarely covers or recommends new books about Mathematics, even in the Popular Science section.

There are $3$ kinds of books that I am talking about

1. *Popular Mathematics* - This may be a book about the *history* of Mathematics or a book intended to explain a *Mathematical concept* to lay audiences. I often find these illuminating.
2. *Problem Solving*  - This may include simple *puzzles* with a quick insightful moment as well as problems that are based on *Olympiads*.
3. *Text Books/Technical Books* - These are books that courses might be built around. However, I'm only looking for text books within my domain of interest i.e. *(Computer Science, Discrete Mathematics, Combinatorics)*.

I'm mostly looking for a regular source of recommendation for the first $2$ categories and not so much the third. I have a huge passion for Mathematics and now that I'm no longer in college, I'd like to continue to learn, stimulate myself and grow.

Here are some of my favourite authors

**Popularising Mathematics** (Historical or Essays)

- Martin Gardener
- Ian Stewart
- Paul Nahin
- Willuam Dunham

**Problem Solving (Olympiad Style) or Fun Puzzles** -

- Ross Honsberger
- Martin Erickson
- Titu Andrescu
- Alexander Soifer

**Lucid Text Books** *(within my areas of interest - Discrete Mathematics, Combinatorics, Number Theory, etc)*

- Miklos Bona
- Jiri Matousek

This is not an exhaustive list, but it's just meant to give an idea of the kind of writing I like or the kind of material I am looking for. As you can probably tell, most of the writers on my list are not releasing new books every year and that is the reason for this question. I'd love to keep track of the latest releases and reviews !

Here's what I'm looking for

- A *Blog/Website* - Which discusses reviews of latest releases
- A *Podcast* - *Physics World* announces a short list of $10$ books of the year at the end of every year. I would love a similar list for *Mathematics* !
- An *Award Short or Long List* - There are all sorts of awards like the *GoodReads Choice Awards, The Pulitzer, The Booker, The Hugo Awards, Royal Society Prizes for Science Books, etc*. I love going through these longlists and shortlists and it fuels my book recommendations in other genres. I would love for them to cover Mathematics too !

Let's make a list here !

Comment: The *American Mathematica Monthly* and the *Mathematical Gazette* regularly have book reviews.

Comment: @Anonymous Are they paid magazines ?

Comment: Yes, but you can probably see a limited number of back issues for free on Jstor with an e-mail account. If you have institutional access, you can use that.

Comment: By any chance, do you know if they deliver print versions of these magazines outside the US ?